# Android Floating Action does not response on click

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

can you tell me why my FAB does not react on click? Here is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView wView;
FloatingActionButton fab;
EditText source, target;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;
    source = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sourceAddr);
    target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.targetAddr);

    wView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton ) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String sourceAddr = source.getText().toString();
            String targetAddr = source.getText().toString();

            if (sourceAddr.trim().length() > 0 && targetAddr.trim().length() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, sourceAddr + ", "  +targetAddr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
    WebSettings settings = wView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wView.loadUrl("file:////android_asset/web/index.html");
}
```

}

And here is my layout xml ... is too long so I uploaded it into pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/f3UfXGxa
I am using API 22.

Comment: Have you fill the both edit text with value before using the fab ?

Comment: Yes, I do not know why Toast not works, but when I try snackbar, then works. So problem will be with Toasts.

Comment: Let me know if my post have solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
 Toast.makeText(context, sourceAddr + ", "  +targetAddr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You forget to call the show() method .